# How to include js and css files without require using Webpack

Tags: webpack

I am building a a Web Application which will also include a game built with [PhaserJS](http://phaser.io/). For the user interface I am using Angular Material. As a frontend framework I use AngularJS 1.5. My problem is that I have started to implement this Application on a Mac and my setup worked just fine. However, now I have to continue on a Windows Desktop and somehow the `copy-webpack-plugin` does not seem to work anymore. If I run my production build it looks fine, means the plugin copies the files to the `lib` folder. Now, if I start the dev-server the files are missing. The reason why I copy those files is that I do not want to re-compile them because if I do so, my build takes for ever (almost 3 min). In addition Phaser comes pre-built which includes `PIXI` and `p2` as well and I dont want to require those two as well.

What is wrong? Is there another way to use *static* files such as `phaser.min.js` and `angular-material.min.css` so that those will only be copied and included to the `index.html`? How would you deal with such a situation?

Here is my `webpack.config.js`:

```
var path = require('path'),
    webpack = require('webpack'),
    HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin'),
    CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin'),
    ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

var node_modules = path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules');
var src = path.join(__dirname, 'src');
var app = path.join(src, 'app');
var dist = path.join(__dirname, 'dist');
var lib = path.join(__dirname, 'lib');

var vendors = [];

// Vendor scripts
var libs = [{
  name: 'phaser',
  path: path.join(node_modules, 'phaser/build/phaser.min.js')
}, {
  name: 'angular-material',
  path: path.join(node_modules, 'angular-material/angular-material.min.css')
}];

// Include all vendor scripts
libs.forEach(function (vendor) {
  vendors.push({
    from: vendor.path,
    to: path.join(lib, vendor.name)
  });
});

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    'app': path.join(app, 'app.ts'),
    'vendor': path.join(app, 'vendor.ts')
  },
  output: {
    path: dist,
    filename: '[name]-[hash:6].js',
    publicPath: './'
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: src
  },
  devtool: 'eval',
  module: {
    loaders: [{
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loader: 'ng-annotate?add=true!ts',
        exclude: [
          /node_modules/
        ]
      }, {
        test: /\.json/,
        loader: 'json'
      }, {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: 'raw'
      }, {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: "style!css"
      }, {
        name: 'styles',
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style",
          "css?sourceMap!autoprefixer?browsers=last 2 versions!sass?sourceMap"),
        exclude: [
          /node_modules/
        ]
      }, {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: 'file?name=images/[name].[ext]'
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.ts', '.js', '.html', '.scss']
  },
  plugins: [
    new CopyWebpackPlugin(vendors),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'vendor',
      filename: '[name].js',
      minChunks: Infinity
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css'),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: 'index.html',
      template: path.join(src, 'index.html'),
      inject: 'body'
    })]
};
```

Comment: Can you try dropping the copy plugin and using [noParse](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#module-noparse) against phaser/... ?

Comment: I did use noParse now. I need to import some other dependencies that Phaser relies on but I guess its ok. Now everything is in my vendor bundle. Also the angualar-material css.

Comment: @bebraw Do you know how I can speed up my build? Takes for ever to build and recompile. Anything you can see in my config?

Comment: It can be a good idea to set up a `include` path (or paths, array works too) per each loader definition. This can help a lot.

Comment: Ok, will look into that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your plugin copy-webpack-plugin

https://github.com/kevlened/copy-webpack-plugin/issues/26

Try downgrading it to version `1.0` it looks like that's the problem. They must be accidentally doing some Mac specific CLI command in the latest version.

Comment: Unfortunately not working. Not even when I downgrade to version 1.0.0. It still doesnt copy those files while in dev-mode. It does work for my production build though... which is weird.